# Connect to SVN through Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, eclipse

We have a Subversion server running on an internal server.  I'm trying to connect to it through SubClipse (Eclipse) on Ubuntu.

When I enter the URL:  svn://servername/site/trunk  as I do from Windows.  I get the following error:

Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Malformed network data"

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had a lot more success using Subversive and not Subclipse.  Subversive is also an Eclipse incubator project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got ssh access to the machine 'servername'? If so you could try :

```
svn+ssh://username@servername/site/trunk
```

If you post more of the error log it would be easier to help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check if the subversion version you use is the same the servers uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check your proxy settings in Window > Preferences > Network too.

Answer (score 1):

Try http protocol and not svn protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a number of different things.  I un-installed everything, eclipse, subversion, subclipse, etc.  Re-installed, then everything worked fine.

That's linux for ya.

Thanks for the tips anyway.